# How do I get Windows username of other system accessing my inhouse website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

My requirement for a web application is that I need the Windows username of the machine accessing my web site as login credentials. This is an inhouse web application, hosted in IIS 7.0.

I had already set the authentication to Windows and had also added following code to retrieve username:

```
string domainName = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
string[] s = domainName.Split('.');
string userName = s[0] + "\\" + Dns.GetHostName();
Session["UserName"] = userName;
```

Are there any other settings left out?

Please tell me how would that be done.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
User.Identity.Name
```